# Strange case of settings in app.config file and underlying class

Tags: c#, console-application, app-config

this is very strange.

I have created an app.config file with some settings.

Visual Studio creates a class to manage the settings "easily", but, for some reason, when I call

```
Properties.Settings.Default.UrlImportacion
```

The default setting is retrieved (the one that was set at design time). When I change the value in app.config file, only the default one is retrieved.

I tried adding the settings in applicationSettings group and in userSettings group. No matter what I do, system always get the default setting.

Is there an explanation to this?

Thanks
Jaime

Comment: Are you changing the app.config file before running the application?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya yes. To solve the problem momentarily, I had to build the project with setting I need. By the way, This is a class library project. All the changes I am making in the app.config file of the .exe project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Application scoped settings are read only and can be changed at design time or by altering the `.config` file in between application sessions.

User scoped settings can be written at runtime, but if you change/delete/add a setting you need to call `Properties.Settings.Default.Save();` method to save your changes on settings between application sessions; Otherwise the settings may get cleared each time a change is detected.

To check whether your changes are persisted or not, you can find user settings stored here `%userprofile%\appdata\local` or `%userprofile%\Local Settings\Application Data`.

**Update**

If I understand you well, this solution will work for you.

I tried to simulate your situation by copying content of bin folder to new project and changing `ProjectName.exe.config` and `App.config` file manually, the default value (in old project) for `Color` was `Green` but my expected value was `Purple`.

**This section is what I've added to both `ProjectName.exe.config` and `App.config` files**:

```
<userSettings>
    <Namespace.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="Color" serializeAs="String">
        <value>Purple</value>
      </setting>
    </Namespace.Properties.Settings>
</userSettings>
```

After doing the above output of `Properties.Settings.Default.Color` was `Green`.

But why this is happening? Because default values are cached, and if the franework is not able to access or open the `config` file it will use the defaults instead.

Obviously the problem has a solution. You can solve it simply by calling `Reload` method before trying to read the value:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Reload();
var color = Properties.Settings.Default.Color;
```

As described in [its documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.applicationsettingsbase.reload?view=netframework-4.8):

> The Reload method clears the currently cached property values, causing a reload of these values from persistent storage when they are subsequently accessed. This method performs the following actions:
>
> - It clears the currently cached properties by clearing the collection represented by the PropertyValues property.
> - It raises the PropertyChanged event for every member of the Properties collection.
>
> Reload contrasts with [Reset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.applicationsettingsbase.reset?view=netframework-4.8) in that the former will load the last set of saved application settings values, whereas the latter will load the saved default values.

Comment: Hello... maybe question is not clear. But, I am changing content of app.config file manually.... before launching the application.

Comment: If you're editing the `app.config` in your bin directory, that gets overwritten on every build. You should check the directory I mentioned in answer.

Comment: it isn't clear yet. I am deploying the application. After I build the app, of course .config file is overwritten. Then, I take all the bin folder content, create a folder in other computer and place the file in it. Finally,  I need to configure the system with the parameters the other computer needs. The goal of a .config file is precisely that, To be able to configure the system without recompiling with the target settings embedded. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: it is a shame but it did not work, but this is related to the class library project. I have a console application and a class library project. To test, I have changed a setting in the app.config file of the application and start debugging. By using immediate window, I realized that the setting is retrieved correctly without calling the reload() method. That is perfect. However, I have called a class library method, and I get the changed property value. The value retrieved was the default one. Then, I called the reload() method, and the same. Class library project does not like it.

Comment: I'll be glad if I can help you. If you have only one config file for both of the projects then you have couple of choices, first replace `Reload()` with `Upgrade()`, if it's not working, try with `ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("userSettings");`, if still it's not working, why not, test `Reset()`. You mentioned: *I realized that the setting is retrieved correctly without calling the reload() method*; in this case, you can assign it to a variable inside console app and then pass the right value to class library instead of direct accessing it from library (if there is no limit by design).

Comment: But if you have two config files (one for library and one for console app) you have to merge them into console application `app.config` file. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1399399/12217161) is how you can merge your config files.

Comment: thanks!! finally I figured out. I have read the link you posted about merging the files and just now I have realized about my mistake. The problem was the namespace used in the exe app.config file. I was using <ExeNamespace.Properties.Settings> all the time. What I had to use was <LibNamespace.Properties.Settings>